# how to receive push notifications even when the play services are disabled on android

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

As you know firebase uses play services to push notifications but I am working on an android app that requires to receive push notifications even when the play services are disabled and the phone is on power saving.

I have tried using pushy but the app do not receive notifications in power saving mode, I have also tried using a foreground service but it is of no good.

Comment: I don't think Android will allow you to do that. You can't break those rules. Perhaps you can use local notifications, if the actual timing is locally predictable.

Comment: @Jorn thanks for your response, can you please tell me more about local notifications, Do you mean the app itself schedules and triggers the display of notifications based on predefined events or conditions like alarm apps?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible without modifying the device.  Individual apps do not have the ability to control the device when it's trying to save power.  Otherwise, *every* app would do this, and the device's battery life would suffer as a result.  You have to either depend on Play services to manage the notification, or accept that you can't do anything at all while power saving.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think you are right but I still need something that works :(

Comment: You're going to have to readjust your requirements, or manufacture your own device that does what you want. Google has learned that battery life is far more important to end users than 100% reliable instant notifications from apps.

Comment: my own device, Are you sure ? that's a big statement. I think a custom OS will do the job.

Comment: Sure, and you'll have to find a way to put it on your own devices.  Manually flashing other people's devices doesn't really scale, so your app's distribution will be extremely limited. A full discussion of your options is way outside the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: I am not interested in manufacturing my own devices or anything like that, I want a somewhat general solution, please suggest me something that you think will somehow resolve the problem, like it will send notifications on most of the devices. I can go with these type of solutions.

Comment: If I had a suggestion, I would have put it in the answer.  I don't think what you're trying to do is feasible for consumer devices, and you're not the first person who has tried.

Answer (score -2):

Alright.
Unfortunately, it is not possible to receive Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) notifications without Google Play Services on Android devices. FCM relies on the Google Play Services infrastructure to deliver notifications to devices.

Similarly, power saving mode on Android devices restricts background activity, which can prevent apps from receiving notifications.

One possible workaround is to use a third-party push notification service that does not rely on Google Play Services and provides support for power saving mode. Some examples of such services include OneSignal, Pusher, and Amazon SNS.

Comment: Thanks for your response but these third party services still somehow depends on either FCM or background services

Comment: ChatGPT usage is not allowed

Comment: @0x150 what do you mean?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow.  It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since most or all 6 of recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: The much higher answer rate and the verboseness suggest this has been generated by [ChatGPT_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned).

Comment: @Qasim Malik: See *[Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)*. It has been been featured in the right-hand panel for more than six months now (under *"Featured on Meta"*). Why isn't it clear (not rethorical question)? What could be done to make it clearer?

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).